# Display 404 error document for invalid urls from apache without hitting rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

Is it possible to show 404.html error document for invalid URLs using RewriteRule from Apache before it hits Rails application.

We have routes like /website/stats_for_season/1031475/23 in our application. But for some reason google bot is accessing URLs like /website/stats_for_season/1031475 without last part.

I have added below rule to  Apache .conf file, without success.

RewriteRule ^website/stats_for_season/([0-9]+)/$ '' [R=404] [L]

Comment: Check this link, it will help you to solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162196/setting-up-rails-app-on-apache-with-passenger-rails-doesnt-seem-to-load

Comment: Rails works fine. Just want to prevent invalid URL formats hitting my application.

Comment: The request will come from your web server apache to application server of rails.