# Ubuntu server with RVM, Phusion Passenger, Apache and Nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ubuntu, nginx, passenger

I have an Ubuntu server 14.04 running with RVM, MySQL, Phussion Passenger and Apache.

In this server I have more than 30 Ruby on Rails projects serving webs through Phussion Passenger and Apache.

I read that Nginx is faster than Apache and I want to try it with some of the projects and leave the others with Apache.

It's posible to have apache2 module and nginx module for passenger installed and runining at same time? And have some projects runing with apache2 module and others with nginx module?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can probably run them both but it sounds like a mess. You will probably be better off with just Nginx and the Passenger module.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use them both at the same server. But only one server can listen 80 port. To avoid this, you may consider using nginx as a proxy server in front of apache. I mean, for those sites which you want to serve them from apache, you may use nginx as a proxy server. And for others you may serve them directly from nginx.

[This](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-apache) is a good tutorial for using nginx as a proxy for apache.

Comment: Thank you! So I can't configure one site with Apache + Passanger like [this site available](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6162224/660942) and other Nginx + Passenger like [this site available](https://gist.github.com/halilim/9950381#vhost-template) and both responding on port 80?

Comment: No, apache and nginx can not listen 80 port at the same time. The best choice is using nginx as a proxy server.